# iPhone API: SIP RTP SRTP ZRTP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voip

I would like to ask if there are, one of this Api: `SIP` `RTP` `SRTP` `ZRTP` 
for iPhone, if there is a way for to use them in the iPhone Simulator, and what is the
default gateway in iPhone .

Comment: hey have you found anything? I'm looking to get SIP functionality like chat and voice calls?

Answer (score 2):

A very good framework for voip is [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org) which is open source under dual license (free and commercial) and provide support for SIP/TLS and SRTP.

ZORG is an open source ZRTP implementation along with pjsip [integration](http://www.zrtp.org).

Answer (score 0):

None of these are built into iOS. There are some SIP apps, but I believe the developers of those apps had to write their own C/C++ libraries for those protocols.